# Getting the next login

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to get the correct Login and Logout based on a series of attendance record. Here is a sample data.

```
employee_id logdatetime         tkstype
  PH120013  2012-08-25 08:30:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-25 13:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-26 02:30:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-27 15:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-27 17:00:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-27 21:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-28 08:00:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-28 19:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-29 03:30:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-29 21:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-30 05:30:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-30 19:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-08-31 05:30:00.000 0
  PH120013  2012-08-31 20:30:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-09-01 01:00:00.000 1
  PH120013  2012-09-01 21:00:00.000 0
```

TKSTYPE = 0 - IN 1 - OUT

My dilemma is to get the next login based on the user query date. So that I can get the correct logout of the user. For example, I want to see the login for user PH120013 and the date is 2012-08-26. My desired output will be:

```
          IN                              OUT
```

PH120013  2012-08-26 02:30:00.000          2012-08-27 15:00:00.000

Here is my complete query:

```
;With Attendance_CTE As 
(

        SELECT employee_id,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), logdatetime, 120) logdate,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), logdatetime, 114) logtime,logdatetime,tkstype
        FROM MSTR_ATTENDANCE WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), logdatetime, 120) >='2012-08-26'

),
Employee_CTE As
(
    SELECT employee_id,
       '2012-08-26' + CONVERT(datetime,tks_ofc_in,108) as Official_IN, 
       '2012-08-26' + CONVERT(datetime,tks_ofc_out,108) as Official_OUT,
       hireddate + '00:00:00.000' as HiredDate_DateTime,           
       '2012-08-26' + ' 00:00:00.000' as TKS_DateTime
    FROM vwu_Employee_Contract_Info                 
),
Min_Max_Attendance As
(
    SELECT t_in.employee_id,
           min(isnull(t_in.logdatetime,'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')) min_in,
           max(isnull(t_out.logdatetime,'1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')) max_out 
    FROM
        (SELECT employee_id,logdatetime FROM Mstr_Attendance WHERE tkstype=0) t_in
    LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT employee_id,logdatetime FROM Mstr_Attendance WHERE tkstype=1) t_out
    ON
        t_in.employee_id=t_out.employee_id      
    GROUP BY
        t_in.employee_id
)
SELECT Attendance_CTE.Employee_ID,logdatetime,
       CASE WHEN TKSType=0 THEN
           CASE Min_Max_Attendance.min_in 
                -- first day
                WHEN '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 
                    CASE
                        -- check if current logdatetime is within the hireddate and current date query
                        WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime BETWEEN HiredDate_DateTime AND TKS_DateTime 
                        THEN 
                            CASE
                                WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime BETWEEN Employee_CTE.Official_In AND 
                                     Employee_CTE.Official_Out THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime                                                                                                                           
                            END 
                        ELSE
                        -- no time in?
                                '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                    END
                ELSE
                    -- regular days
                    CASE
                        -- check whether no out
                        WHEN Min_Max_Attendance.max_out = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN Attendance_CTE.Logdatetime
                    ELSE
                        -- but with previous out
                        CASE
                            -- check whether logdatetime is not greater than the TKS_DateTime
                            WHEN  Convert(varchar(10),Attendance_CTE.logdatetime,120) !> TKS_DateTime THEN                              
                                  CASE
                                    -- when logdatetime range on employee official time including late
                                    WHEN Attendance_CTE.logdatetime BETWEEN Employee_CTE.Official_In AND Employee_CTE.Official_Out THEN Attendance_CTE.Logdatetime
                                    -- when logdatetime is less than the max l_out on the records
                                    WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime <= Min_Max_Attendance.max_out THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime
                                    -- when logdatetime is on range between the min l_in and max l_out on the records
                                    WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime BETWEEN Min_Max_Attendance.min_in AND Min_Max_Attendance.max_out THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime
                                    -- when logdatetime is on range between current query date to official in 
                                    WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime BETWEEN TKS_DateTime AND Employee_CTE.Official_In THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime                                   
                                    -- when logdatetime is not greater than equal to current query date 
                                    WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime < TKS_DateTime THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime
                                  END
                            /*ELSE
                                -- no time in?
                                '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000'*/
                        END 
                    END
            END 
        END ActualLogIn,
        CASE WHEN TKSType=1 THEN                 
             CASE
                -- check whether logdatetime is less than  official_out and greater than official_in, undertime
                WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime > Employee_CTE.Official_Out AND Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime !> Employee_CTE.Official_In
                THEN    Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime
                -- logdatetime is greater than official out and not greater than the next log in                                    
                WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime >= Employee_CTE.Official_Out AND Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime !> '2012-08-27 17:00:00.000'
                    THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime                         
                WHEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime !> '2012-08-27 17:00:00.000'
                THEN Attendance_CTE.LogDateTime                     
             END
        END ActualLogOut            
FROM Employee_CTE
LEFT JOIN Attendance_CTE
ON
    Employee_CTE.Employee_ID=Attendance_CTE.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN Min_Max_Attendance
ON
    Employee_CTE.Employee_ID=Min_Max_Attendance.Employee_ID
AND
    Attendance_CTE.Employee_ID=Min_Max_Attendance.Employee_ID
WHERE 
    Employee_CTE.Employee_ID IN ('PH120012','PH120013')
```

- 2012-08-27 17:00:00.000' <-- hardcoded, this is the one I need to get correctly

Comment: I cannot fingure out what you really want. Given an employee_id and a datetime, find the closest logout datetime relative to the given datatime? Or you want to output the attendance records with In and its corresponding Out in one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Since I am not sure about the database, this is a generic solution, and this will work in almost all databases

```
select * from (
select logi_in.logdatetime as 'IN' , logi_out.logdatetime as 'OUT' 
from MSTR_ATTENDANCE logi_in
left outer join MSTR_ATTENDANCE logi_out
on logi_in.employee_id=logi_out.employee_id
and logi_in.tkstype=0
and logi_out.logdatetime =(
select     MIN(logdatetime)  
             from       MSTR_ATTENDANCE MSTR   
             where      MSTR.employee_id = logi_out.employee_id  
             and        MSTR.tkstype = 1
             and        MSTR.logdatetime > logi_in.logdatetime 
       )
and logi_in.employee_id='PH120013'
and logi_in.logdatetime='2012-08-26 02:30:00.000')t
where OUT is not null
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4eb9/3)

Comment: @davidfaber yes sql server 2005

Comment: ,I just tweak your script but it greatly illuminate my mind. Thank you!